# Python list not appending & variable not defined

Tags: python

I am having one small problem with my program and as I am very new to Python am struggling to find a solution. I have googled about a bit but nothing seemed to work from what I tried. My code is the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from pandas import *

def maze_gen():
    ##Opens the Image
    im_file = Image.open('15x15.png')

    ##Reads the image pixel information
    arr = misc.imread('15x15.png')

    ##Sets the width, height and maze size variables
    width = im_file.size[0]
    height = im_file.size[1]
    size = width * height

    ##Defines the mapping, start and end points array
    map = np.zeros([width, height], dtype=np.int)
    start_pos = np.empty(shape=[1,2])
    end_pos = np.empty(shape=[1,2])

    ##Search image replacing white pixels with 1's in the mapping array
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            if 255 in arr[x,y]:
                map[x,y] = 1

    ##Find the start and end locations
    for x in range(width):
        if map[0,x] > 0:
            start_pos = 0,x

    for x in range(width):
        if map[height -1 ,x] > 0:
            end_pos = height -1 ,x



    return width, height, size, map, start_pos, end_pos

def check_neighbours(col, row):
    width, height, size, map, start_pos, end_pos=maze_gen()

    neighbours = list()

    ##Debugging to check cell_current values are correct
    print('col =', col)
    print('row =', row)

    if (col >= 0 and col < height and row >= 0 and row < width):
            neighbours.append((col, row))
            print('Neighbours', neighbours, '\n')

    if (len(neighbours) > 0):
        return neighbours
    else:
        return None

def solver():
    width, height, size, map, start_pos, end_pos=maze_gen()

    ##Sets cell_current to the starting position    
    cell_current = start_pos

    path = list()
    path.append((cell_current))

    check_neighbours(cell_current[0]-1, cell_current[1]) ##Top neighbour
    check_neighbours(cell_current[0], cell_current[1]+1) ##Right neighbour
    check_neighbours(cell_current[0]+1, cell_current[1]) ##Bottom neighbour
    check_neighbours(cell_current[0], cell_current[1]-1) ##Left neighbour

    print('Neighbours in Solver', neighbours, '\n')

def debug():
    width, height, size, map, start_pos, end_pos=maze_gen()

    ##Prints maze information for debugging
    print ('Maze width:', width)
    print ('Maze height:', height)
    print ('Maze size:', size, '\n')

    ##Print Start and End points
    print ('Start Point')
    print (start_pos, '\n')
    print ('End Point')
    print (end_pos, '\n')

    ##Prints mapping array for debugging
    print ('Mapping Array')
    print (DataFrame(map), '\n')

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    solver()
```

The issues I am running into are the list neighbours isn't being added to with each successful run through of the if statement. Instead of getting the following readout:

> col = -1 row = 1 Neighbours []
>
> col = 0 row = 2 Neighbours [(0, 2)]
>
> col = 1 row = 1 Neighbours [(1, 1)]
>
> col = 0 row = 0 Neighbours [(0, 0)]

Any help on this problem would be amazing. Please do bare in mind that I am very new to python so any stupid mistakes or things I could change to make the code better please do say!

Comment: As the error tells you `neighbours` is not defined. Why / where do you believe it should be?

Comment: From my understanding it is defined within the check_neighbours function which is called before the print line is.

Comment: Yes but it is local to that function. You should read about variable scope...

Comment: Thank you for your help I have fixed that issue now its just the issue of the list not appending....

Comment: well then edit your question to reflect your new problem...

Comment: It was already in there but I removed the fluff that was no longer relevant

Comment: @KaiJones you should really strive to provide a [mcve]. There's a lot of extraneous stuff here, that isn't really relevant to your question. Try to re-create the problem you are seeing using a small, self-contained example

Comment: Side-note (that may cause correctness issues for non-square inputs): You're testing `row` against `width` and `col` against `height`. Traditionally, the `row` would be paired with `height` (because row 0 is the "top" row, row 1 is "below" it, etc.), while `col` would be paired with `width` (because col 0 is the "leftmost" column, col 1 is to the "right" of it, etc.). Your code seems to mix them up in many places (possibly even consistently; maybe you're an incorrigible Fortran programmer :-) ), but I figured I'd mention it in case it's inconsistent.

Comment: You redefine `neighbours` to an empty list everytime before appending a new element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make two changes in your code:

1. Make **neighbours** variable global.
2. Replace **neighbours.append((col, row))** with **neighbours.append([col, row])**. This is because you can only append a variable or a list to an existing list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: #2 is completely wrong. You can `append` anything to a `list`. Appending `tuple`s is no different from appending any other type, and using `tuple`s is more efficient on memory and speed when you don't need to mutate the sequence later (Python heavily optimizes the use of short `tuple`s because they're used implicitly all over the place, and explicitly as lightweight pseudo-objects as in this case).